# Firebase custom model inference speed vs Tensorflow Lite

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite, firebase-mlkit

I trained an object detection model (based on ssd mobilenet v1) and converted it to tflite (with no quantization, the model is still FLOAT).
I ran the model using `firebase-ml-model-interpreter` (v20.0.1) on a camera feed (resized to 300x300). Code in Kotlin.

Then I did the same using `tensorflow-lite` (v1.14.0). Code in Java.

Inference in firebase is slower with some unpleasant spikes compared to TF, I am trying to understand why as I really want to use Firebase as it is already included in my project.

Here is the inference speed comparison (100 camera frames for each, same frame as the phone was still). Firebase app uses the [CameraView](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView) component while TF app uses Camera API directly.
[image: TF vs MLKIT inference time]

And here is the relevant code for each:

### Firebase with Kotlin

```
fun loadModel() {
    ...
    // Load local model
    interpreter = FirebaseModelInterpreter.getInstance(modelOptions)

    dataOptions = FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions.Builder()
        .setInputFormat(0, dataType, intArrayOf(1, 300, 300, 3))
        .setOutputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.FLOAT32, intArrayOf(1, 10, 4)) // Boxes
        .setOutputFormat(1, FirebaseModelDataType.FLOAT32, intArrayOf(1, 10)) // Classes
        .setOutputFormat(2, FirebaseModelDataType.FLOAT32, intArrayOf(1, 10)) // Scores
        .setOutputFormat(3, FirebaseModelDataType.FLOAT32, intArrayOf(1)) // Num detections
        .build()

    val numBytesPerChannel = 4 // Float
    imgData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1 * 300 * 300 * 3 * numBytesPerChannel)
    imgData.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
    ...
}

fun runModel() {
    ...
    imgData.rewind()
    for (x in 0 until 300) {
        for (y in 0 until 300) {
            imgData.putFloat(...) // R
            imgData.putFloat(...) // G
            imgData.putFloat(...) // B
        }
    }

    val inputs = FirebaseModelInputs.Builder().add(imgData).build()
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    interpreter.run(inputs, dataOptions)
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            val elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start
            Log.i(TAG, "Detection finished $elapsed msec - MLKIT")
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            // Handle Error
        }
}
```

### Tensorflow-Lite with Java

```
void loadModel() {
    ...
    tfLite = new Interpreter(modelFile);
    tfLite.setNumThreads(4);

    int numBytesPerChannel = 4 // Float
    imgData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1 * 300 * 300 * 3 * numBytesPerChannel)
    imgData.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
    ...
}

void runModel() {
    ...
    imgData.rewind()
    for (int i = 0; i < 300; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 300; ++j) {
            imgData.putFloat(...) // R
            imgData.putFloat(...) // G
            imgData.putFloat(...) // B
        }
    }

    outputLocations = new float[1][10][4];
    outputClasses = new float[1][10];
    outputScores = new float[1][10];
    numDetections = new float[1];

    Object[] inputArray = {imgData};
    Map<Integer, Object> outputMap = new HashMap<>();
    outputMap.put(0, outputLocations);
    outputMap.put(1, outputClasses);
    outputMap.put(2, outputScores);
    outputMap.put(3, numDetections);

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    tfLite.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputArray, outputMap);
    long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    LOGGER.w("Detection finished %d msec - TF", elapsed);
}
```

Any ideas why it might happen?
thx